# I can't copy/paste files, but I can copy/paste text. What can i do to fix this? (I'm using Win7.)

Tags: copy-paste

I can copy/paste text in Notepad, Word, etc., but I can't copy/paste shortcuts on desktop, shortcuts in explorer, files, etc.

I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: Do you have enough rights? Can you just create files where you want to paste some?

Comment: How does it fail?  Do you get error messages?